# android studio - App with library project fails to assembleRelease

Tags: android, proguard

Here is my build.gradle following:
apply plugin: 'android'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.4"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("***")
            storePassword "***"
            keyAlias "***"
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug{
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

I want to generate signed apk.But when I try to run 'gradle assembleRelease', I get the following:

```
    Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat: can't find refe
    renced class com.actionbarsherlock.BuildConfig
    Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
             If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
             the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolved
    class)
   :education:proguardRelease FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

When I add the '-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**' to the proguard file, the sherlock is also obfuscated. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can set dontwarn only on the com.actionbarsherlock.BuildConfig like this:

```
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.BuildConfig
```